# find the gradient of the curve at the points where it crosses straight line

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Find the gradient of the curve $y = x \sqrt{4-x^2}$ at the points where it crosses the straight line $y=x$

I've calculated $f'(x) = \frac{4}{\sqrt{4-x^2}}$, but I'm not clear what to do next.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The derivative should be $$f'(x) \frac{4-2x^2}{\sqrt{4-x^2}}$$

Now, to find the point where $f(x)= x\sqrt{4-x^2}\,$ intersects the line $y = x$, we set them equal to one another, and solve for $x$.

$$x\sqrt{4-x^2} = x\iff x\sqrt{4-x^2} - x = 0 \iff x(\sqrt{4-x^2} - 1) = 0$$ $$ \implies (x = 0)\;\text{ or }\; (\sqrt{4-x^2} - 1= 0)$$ $$ \implies x = 0,\; \text{ or }\; x= \sqrt 3, \;\text{ or }\;x = -\sqrt 3)$$

Then evaluate $f'(x)$ at each of the values $x = 0, x = -\sqrt 3, x=\sqrt 3$.

Comment: the answer is -2,2,-2

Comment: me too actually find the wrong answer my answer is 2 but the proper answer is -2,2,-2

Comment: You need to use the values of $x$ to determine $f'(0), f'(\sqrt 3)$ and $f'(-\sqrt 3)$. You'll obtain $2, -2, $ and $-2$ respectively.

Comment: i should use the f′(0),f′(3√) and f′(−3√) in the f'(x)??

Comment: Yes, and when you do, you'll obtain $f'(0) = 2$ and $f'(\sqrt 3) = f'(-\sqrt 3) = -2$.

Answer (score 0):

$$y=x\iff x\sqrt{4-x^2}=x\iff \sqrt{4-x^2}=1\iff x=\pm \sqrt 3,$$
and so, the answer is $f'\left(-\sqrt 3\right)$ and $f'\left(\sqrt 3\right)$ where

$$f'(x)=\frac{d}{dx}\left(x\sqrt{4-x^2}\right)=\sqrt{4-x^2}-\frac{x^2}{\sqrt{4-x^2}}.$$